# Dictionary won't persist with NHibernate 3.0

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following entity:

```
public class Alert
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<CxChannel, string> Messages { get; set; }
}

public enum CxChannel
{
    Message,
    Email
}
```

and following mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Entities.Alert, Entities" table="alert">
  <id name="Id" type="int" unsaved-value="0" access="property">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>

  <property name="Name" column="name"/>
    <map name="Messages" table="alert_message" cascade="all">
      <key column="alert_id"/>
      <index column="channel" type="Entities.CxChannel, Entities"/>
      <element column="message" type="System.String"/>
    </map>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem is that when I save an alert entity, Messages dictionary is not persisted to database. As a matter of fact my code looks like the code Oren used in his blog post: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/03/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-ltmapgt.aspx

Has anyone experienced same issue?

Comment: Are you committing the transaction?

Comment: Yes Diego. Besides, alert table is populated with its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your channel column is an integer in your schema as the CxChannel enum will be mapped as 0 (for Message) and 1 (for email). I just pasted your code and mappings into a console project, used new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false), and successfully inserted rows into the generated database.

Comment: Thanks James. channel column is an integer in my schema. Interesting that you could get it to work. I'll use your approach and see what I can find.

Comment: I wonder if there is something odd about your schema. I would do a SchemaExport into a clean database and then diff the generated schema and your schema using a tool like DataDude or RedGate SQL Compare. (BTW - I was using NH3 build 3.0.0.2001. Shouldn't make a difference, but just in case...)

Comment: I tried the same way you explained and NHibernate didn't insert data in alert_message. Did you query back to see if you get the same data you inserted in Messages? I set show_sql=true for NHibernate and lazy=false for the map and noticed that NHinbernate generates INSERT only for alert. But when I tried to load the data, it retrieves from alert_message as well.

Comment: I verified that INSERTs to both tables were being sent using NHProf and viewed the data in those tables using SQL Server Management Studio. Verify that you're using the latest NH3 bits (just in case there was a bug fix). If you still can't get it working, I can drop my sample with binaries into GitHub.

Comment: I'm using NHibernate 3.0 Beta 2 (3.0.0.2002). I appreciate if you drop your sample in github for me to compare with mine.

Comment: I've dropped the sample project into GitHub. You'll want to take a look at the NhHacking project. (You can safely ignore the other projects. Just there for answering other StackOverflow questions.) https://github.com/JamesKovacs/JamesKovacs.StackOverflow/tree/master/NhHacking/

Comment: Found the problem James, thanks to your code. I was missing [Transaction(TransactionMode.Requires)] attribute in my code to initiate transaction. Silly oversight!